# How to Refresh JTable Every Time i Click Search Button

Tags: java, sql-server, swing

```
 try {
            DataBase DB = new DataBase();
            Connection con = DB.Connect();
            String sql;
            sql = "select Id,Name,FatherName, City, Address, Department,RStatus, DatePlacement\n"
                    + "from ECL where "
                    + "id like ? and  "
                    + "name like ? and FatherName like ? and "
                    + "City like ? and Address like ?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, "%" + SearchId.getText() + "%");
            pst.setString(2, "%" + SearchName.getText() + "%");
            pst.setString(3, "%" + SearchFatherName.getText() + "%");
            pst.setString(4, "%" + SearchCity.getText() + "%");
            pst.setString(5, "%" + SearchAddress.getText() + "%");
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int MetaColum = rsmd.getColumnCount(); //adding colums in Jtable
            Vector col = new Vector();
            for (int i = 1; i <= MetaColum; i++) {
                col.addElement(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
            }
            ReTable.setColumnIdentifiers(col);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector rows = new Vector(); // to add rows in Jtable
                for (int j = 1; j <= MetaColum; j++) {
                rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
                }
                ReTable.addRow(rows);
                ResultTable.setModel(ReTable);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }      
         ReTable.fireTableDataChanged(); // Method to refresh the Jtable
    }
```

how to refresh jtable with new data. it loads new data but it also contain the old data every time i search for new name it give me the correct result but the previous search data also remains in jtable. my question is how to refresh jtable every time i make a new search. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: ReTable.fireTableDataChanged(); did not work jtable.repaint(); also not worked. and i am new with programing..

Comment: ResultTable.setModel(ReTable); should be instead of ReTable.fireTableDataChanged();

Comment: rest (e.g ReTable.setColumnIdentifiers(col);) depends of your XxxTableModel,

Comment: ReTable.fireTableDataChanged(); reseting all custom changes in model, listeners and changes in the JTables view too

Comment: Thanks for your Help at last i done it by adding simple line of code before try catch block. **ReTable.setRowCount(0);** just set tablemodel row count to zero and it works. Love you all thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not removing the previous rows inserted in your model *ReTable*. In each call you are adding more and more rows in this line:

```
         ReTable.addRow(rows);
```

Remove all rows from the model before launching the query or create a new model fresh with no rows for each query.